# Design of a small scale air curtain

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I am new to the field, most of the papers I have searched directly conduct CFD simulation but skipped the calculation. I hope to get an estimation by calculations.

I am designing a small scale horizontal overhead air curtain covering a 0.5m x 1m (Width x Height) area.

Assume no temperature, air density difference between inside and outside air, no winds or other kinds of draught. Considering an ideal case, and the air curtain is blowing vertically downward,

- $b\times h$ = outlet cross-sectional area
- $L$ = throw distance
- $v_0$ = initial velocity
- $v_L$ = velocity at $L$

---

1. Is there an equation or other numerical methods to determine the relationships between $b$, $h$, $L$, $v_0$ and $v_L$?
2. Also, is it possible to find $b_L\times h_L$ (cross-sectional area of the air stream at $L$)?
3. How to determine optimal outlet cross-sectional area $b \times h$?
4. How to determine optimal air speed vL? (to minimize leakage but also turbulence) (2.5-3.5 m/s for most of the currently existing products)

Are there any relevant considerations I should consider?

What references/sources would be good to read?

Answer (score 0):

1. Imagine the air curtain as a 2D laminar jet ($b/h$ > 20),

Then the velocity along the centre line decays as $L^{-1/3}$.

More clearly, $v_L = \bigg( \frac{3 \rho~ v_0^4~ h^2}{32\nu~ L} \bigg)^{1/3}$ ; where $\nu$ is the kinematic viscosity of air.

2. Yes, possible. But you have to decide what $\%v_L$ defines the edge/boundary of the jet at $L$ for your curtain. Since the jet diffuses laterally by $\sim sec^2y$.

3 & 4. You decide what is your need on $v_L$ or constraint on $v_0$, Then the first point will give you the answer.

If you need a more detailed answer or if your jet is turbulent rather laminar, I would suggest the great book "Boundary-Layer Theory" by  Hermann Schlichting